# Why is this merge sort function returning linked list with zeroes (c++)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I've got this merge sort function

```
namespace sorted{

    template<typename T>
    class list {

        /* other stuff */

        list<T>* slice(int from, int to){
            from = (from < 0) ? 0 : from;
            to = (to > this->len) ? this->len : to;
            list<T>* result = new list<T>();
            node<T> *n = this->head;
            int idx = 0;
            while (n && (idx < this->len)){
                if ((from <= idx) && (idx <= to)) result->append(n->value);
                if (idx > to) break;
                n = n->next;
                idx++;
            }
            return result;
        }            
    }

    template<typename T>
    list<T>* merge(list<T>* left, list<T>* right){
        list<T>* result = new list<T>();
        while ((left->length() > 0) || (right->length() > 0)){
            if ((left->length() > 0) && (right->length() > 0)){
                T l = left->get(0);
                T r = right->get(0);
                if (l <= r){
                    result->append(l);
                    left->remove(0);
                } else{
                    result->append(r);
                    right->remove(0);
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (left->length() > 0) {
                result->append(left->get(0));
                left->remove(0);
            }

            if (right->length() > 0) {
                result->append(right->get(0));
                right->remove(0);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    list<T>* merge_sort(list<T>* original){
        if (original->length() <= 1) {
            return original;
        }
        int len = original->length();
        list<T>* left = NULL;
        list<T>* right = NULL;
        if (len > 2){
            left = original->slice(0,(len/2));
            right = original->slice((len/2)+1,len-1);
        }else if (len == 2){
            left = original->slice(0,0);
            right = original->slice(1,1);
        }
        left = merge_sort(left);
        right = merge_sort(right);
        delete original;
        list<T>* result = merge(left, right);
        delete left;
        delete right;
        return result;
    }

    /* other stuff */    
}
```

And here's my main method

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    sorted::list<int>* l = get_random_list();
    l = merge_sort(l);
    for (int i = 0; i < (l->length() - 1); i++){
        int t = l->get(i);
        int u = l->get(i+1); 
        if (t > u){
            sorted::list<int>* m = l->slice(i - 5, i + 5);
            cout << m << endl;
            delete m;
            break;
        }
    }
    delete l;
    return 0;
}
```

Link to [bitbucket.org project](https://bitbucket.org/bitcycle/sorted-in-cpp)

My question *was* this.

If the list is returned properly from the slicing function, why would it not be returned to the main function properly, if its being done the same way?

**[Update]** Added functions as they're currently functioning the way they should be.  A full version is up on bitbucket.

Comment: Some problem with your assignment operator? You _do_ have an assignment operator, don't you?

Comment: How is that merge sort? you merely return one unsorted slice... which is not what you have in your output, though.

Comment: I think he show us simplified version

Comment: With my g++ (version 4.5.1) in Ubuntu 10.10 it works correctly. What is your operating system/compiler?

Comment: By the way, your valgrind check will show that you are accessing invalid memory (in reality, freed up memory). This is as Joachim said due to the fact that you are shallow copying the list, while the destructor of the old one destroys the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking your full code in the link you provided, I can definitely say the problem is because you don't have an assignment operator.

What happens now is that the assignments of the lists will use the default assignment operator that is automatically generated by the compiler. This does a *shallow* copy, so the list on the left hand side of the assignment will have its pointers be the same as for the list on the right hand side. This means that when the local variable you return goes out of scope, it will of course invoke the destructor which deletes the lists. Now the copy have pointers which points to deleted memory, and accessing thos pointers is undefined behavior. This is why it seems to work in one place and not the other.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'you don't have an assignment operator', because I can see assignments all over the place. Do you mean he didn't overwrite the assignment operator of the list? This is not required as he is using STL and if you assign 1 STL list to another it will do a deep copy (this would not have been the case had he been using pointers). Note, not a deep copy of the objects, but rather of the list itself, which is a trivial difference in this case since int's cannot be shallow copied.

Comment: @Dukeling, he is not using `std::list`. He has his own `sorted::list`.

Comment: Oh right, that does seem to be the case. I get a little confused sometimes when people name things exactly the same as some standard library.

Comment: @Joachim, Thanks for that thorough answer.  I'm still getting back into C++, coming from Python, so I really do appreciate the backgound explanation of why it worked somewhere and not somewhere else.